# Java - GridBagLayout components on top disappear on resize

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I use a `JLabel` and in front of it a `JTextField` so that I can represent a defense-like stat with a value. I use the following code:

```
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

    JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Max\\Desktop\\shield.png");
    jl.setIcon(ii);
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    add(jl, gbc);

    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 10, 10);
    JTextField jtf = new JTextField(2);
    jtf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    gbc.ipadx = 10;
    gbc.ipady = 10;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    jtf.setFocusable(false);
    add(jtf, gbc);
```

And get:        [image]

Everything is fine, however, if I try to resize the window, the `JTextField` disappears for ever and only the `JLabel` shows. Why is that so?

Comment: There's no relationship between the label's position and the text field's position

Comment: How do I set such relationship? :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no relationship between the position of the label and the position of the text field, this means that the label and field are free to move independently of each other
2. There is a z-ordering issue, components lower in the container order are painted after those higher in the container order (reverse order), meaning that the label is actually getting painted before the shield when the whole container is updated.  The reason that it might sometimes work is because components can actually be painted independently of each other, meaning that the textfield could actually get painted without need to notify either the parent container or the label

For example...

[image: Shield]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 10, 10);
            JTextField jtf = new JTextField(2);
            jtf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            gbc.ipadx = 10;
            gbc.ipady = 10;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            jtf.setFocusable(false);
            add(jtf, gbc);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            try {
                JLabel jl = new JLabel();
                ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/shield01.png")));
                jl.setIcon(ii);
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                add(jl, gbc);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

A possibly better solution would be to create a "background" component which took an image and painted it as the background of the component and then add your text field to it.

[image: Background]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TestBackground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestBackground();
    }

    public TestBackground() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            try {
                BackgroundPane pane = new BackgroundPane(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/shield02.png")));
                pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                pane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

                JTextField jtf = new JTextField(2);
                jtf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                gbc.ipadx = 10;
                gbc.ipady = 10;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                jtf.setFocusable(false);
                pane.add(jtf, gbc);

                add(pane);
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public BackgroundPane(BufferedImage img) {
            this.img = img;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img != null ? new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()) : super.getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                g.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
            }
        }

    }

}
```